# flutter Container size expand parent area

Tags: flutter

I have a question, why blue Container size will expand all the area, (size not work). thanks

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    width: 256,
    height: 174,
    child: Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: use `alignment:` in outer `Container` - or noooo... better read [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) - the first paragraphs say: *"When someone learning Flutter asks you why some widget with width:100 isn’t 100 pixels wide, the default answer is to tell them to put that widget inside of a Center, right?

Don’t do that.

If you do, they’ll come back again and again, asking why some FittedBox isn’t working, why that Column is overflowing, or what IntrinsicWidth is supposed to be doing. Instead, ..."*

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Since Container combines a number of other widgets each with their own
> layout behavior, Container's layout behavior is somewhat complicated.
>
> Summary: Container tries, in order: to honor alignment, to size itself to the
> child, to honor the width, height, and constraints, to expand to fit the parent,
> to be as small as possible.
>
> (...)
>
> If the widget has an alignment, and the parent provides unbounded
> constraints,
> then the Container tries to size itself around the child.
>
> If the widget has an alignment, and the parent provides bounded constraints, then
> the Container tries to expand to fit the parent, and then positions the child
> within itself as per the alignment.

Try this:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    width: 256,
    height: 174,
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
);
```